# A ação está sendo aplicada em vários elementos, ao invés de um só

Tags: jquery

Tenho o seguinte código aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/felipestoker/SL2EP/3/

Quando eu clico em `homeListagemLiBt` ele mostra a div `buscaAvanHoverDiv`, até aí perfeito! Só que eu vou ter 20 elementos iguais, então, sempre que clico na `homeListagemLiBt` ele mostra todos os `buscaAvanHoverDiv` da página. Teria que criar um número de ID + classe para isso dar certo?

O código é mostrado abaixo:

**HTML:**

```
<li class="homeListagemLi">
    <div class="homeListagemDiv">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <img src="./imagens/pessoa.jpg" height="220" width="220" />
            </li>
            <li><strong>teste</strong>

            </li>
            <li><span>Cargo: Redação</span>

            </li>
            <li><span>Status: Não definido</span>

            </li>
            <li>
                <p>Inscrição: 10/05/2014</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>Última atualização: 10/08/2014</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>Escolaridade: Superir Completo</p>
            </li>
            <li class="homeListagemLiBt"></li>
            <li class="p-relative">
                <div class="buscaAvanHoverDiv">
                    <ul>
                        <li><span>Salário: R$ 1.000,00</span>

                        </li>
                        <li><span>Experiência: haha</span>

                        </li>
                        <li class="clear"></li>
                        <li>
                            <p>Estado civil: Solteiro(a)</p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p>Idiomas: Inglês (intermediário)</p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p>Facebook: fbfbfbf</p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="homeListagemLi">
    <div class="homeListagemDiv">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <img src="./imagens/pessoa.jpg" height="220" width="220" />
            </li>
            <li><strong>teste</strong>

            </li>
            <li><span>Cargo: Redação</span>

            </li>
            <li><span>Status: Não definido</span>

            </li>
            <li>
                <p>Inscrição: 10/05/2014</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>Última atualização: 10/08/2014</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>Escolaridade: Superir Completo</p>
            </li>
            <li class="homeListagemLiBt"></li>
            <li class="p-relative">
                <div class="buscaAvanHoverDiv">
                    <ul>
                        <li><span>Salário: R$ 1.000,00</span>

                        </li>
                        <li><span>Experiência: haha</span>

                        </li>
                        <li class="clear"></li>
                        <li>
                            <p>Estado civil: Solteiro(a)</p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p>Idiomas: Inglês (intermediário)</p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p>Facebook: fbfbfbf</p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(".homeListagemLiBt").click(function () {
    $('.buscaAvanHoverDiv').slideDown();
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.homeListagemLi{
    width: 284px;
    height: 432px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 30px;
    background-color: white;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    position: relative;
}
.homeListagemDiv{
    width: 220px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    height: 380px;
}
.homeListagemDiv>ul>li>img{width: 220px;height: 220px;}
.homeListagemDiv>ul>li>strong{color: #00aeef;font-size: 15px;font-family: "open_sansbold";
}
.homeListagemDiv>ul>li>span{color: #414042;font-size: 13px;font-family: "open_sansbold";
}
.homeListagemDiv>ul>li>p{
    color: #808285;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: "open_sanssemibold";
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.buscaFundoTotalPessoa{
    background-color: #f2f5f6;
    width: 1330px;
    height: 1095px;
    margin: auto;
}
.homeListagemLiBt{
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #e6e7e8;
    background-image: url('../imagens/flechaBaixoCinza.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
/*.homeListagemLiBt:hover .buscaAvanHoverDiv{
    display: block;
}*/
.buscaAvanHoverDiv {
    background-color: #e6e7e8;
    height: 165px;
    left: -31px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 41px;
    width: 285px;
    z-index: 2;
    display: none;
}
.buscaAvanHoverDiv ul{
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-top: 30px;
}
.buscaAvanHoverDiv ul>li>span{
    font-family: 'open_sansbold';
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #414042;
}
.buscaAvanHoverDiv ul>li>p{
    font-family: 'open_sanssemibold';
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #808285;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.buscaPaginacao{width: 144px;float: right;margin-right: 50px;}
.buscaPaginacao li{
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 32px;
    font-family: 'open_sansbold';
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #58595b;
    background-color: white;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.buscaPaginacaoFlecha{
    background-image: url("../imagens/paginacaoDir.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center 10px;
    width:9px;
    height: 24px;

}
.buscaPaginacaoFlecha:hover{
    background-position: center -2px;
}
.buscaPaginacao li:hover {background-color: #58595b;color: white;}
```

Comment: Seu fiddle não funciona e seu HTML é inválido.

Comment: Editei novamente, ele estava no OnLoad, hehe. Não tá 100%, mas dá para ter uma ideia.

Comment: Já testou assim? `$(this).next().find('.buscaAvanHoverDiv').slideDown();`

Comment: @Sergio, funcionou, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma vez que quer fazer slideDown de um elemento descendente do proximo sibling, como este pedaço de HTML:

```
<li class="homeListagemLiBt"></li>
<li class="p-relative">
      <div class="buscaAvanHoverDiv">
```

então, pode usar 
assim com jQuery:

```
$(".homeListagemLiBt").click(function () {
    $(this).next().find('.buscaAvanHoverDiv').slideDown();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Além de confiar em ids ou classes numeradas, você pode também se valer da própria estrutura do HTML:

```
$(this).siblings('li.p-relative').children('div.buscaAvanHoverDiv').slideDown();
```

Essa cadeia de comandos faz o seguinte:

- `$(this)` → Encontra o elemento que disparou o evento
- `siblings('li.p-relative')` → busca as *tags* no mesmo nível da *tag* atual, filtra apenas as que são `li` e possuem a classe `p-relative`.
- `children('div.buscaAvanHoverDiv')`→ busca filhas dessa classe do tipo `div` que possuam a classe `buscaAvanHoverDiv`.

Claro que você não precisa necessariamente tipar tão fortamente (só as classes já seriam o suficiente, mas eu gosto de criar seletores usando boas práticas CSS). Se a *tag* a ser animada sempre for a próxima após a atual você pode usar o método `next` conforme sugestão do Sergio. Caso a `div` possa ser uma descendente indireta do `li` (uma neta, bisneta, etc - que não é o caso do exemplo), substitua o método `children` por `find`.

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aaccioly/Aeg6q/)